# Will the guest OS in virtual box know that it is been accessed by remote display?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, display, remote-desktop

I know there is a feature called "Remote display" in virtual box. My question is if we use that feature, will the guest OS and the software running in the guest OS knows that they have been viewed remotely or being screen shared or something like that. Kindly help me.

Comment: I'm very interested in the "why" driving this question. Average software doesn't care whether it is being viewed via remote session or streamed out elsewhere. If you're so concerned about keeping the fact this is being done from the software in question it leads me to wonder at what it is you are actually trying to do and why it is you are trying to do it.

Comment: @music2myear There is a software that will not run in virtual machine and will not allow screen sharing and also closes all other applications when it is opened. So I thought whether I could fool the application.

Comment: That's more information, but still not really the "why". Why does the application not wish to run in a VM and allow screen recording. It is trivial for an application to see if it is running in a VM. I can pull up that information with a script rather easily and so could any application. It just seems as though you are asking for assistance circumventing controls that may or may not be valid, but considering you are clearly not the author or owner of the application, I'll take their right to their protections over your desires to subvert them.

Comment: @music2myear I was just trying to find the hole in which the application can be tricked and wanted to inform the author of that application to fix that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just viewing it, then no. It's Virtualbox (the hypervisor software) itself streaming output of its virtual video card over RDP. The guest can't tell.

If you're interacting with it, I'm not sure. If it's possible, it's not trivial. It's also just Virtualbox translating your inputs over RDP into virtual hardware inputs. There may be a subtle pattern to it though.

Also please note that by default Virtualbox will emulate a tablet rather than a mouse and it's a pretty unusual configuration for a computer, so it could be one way to detect that the software could be running in a virtual machine. That's independent from remote display though.

Comment: Thanks! for the answer. Is there anyway from the guest OS to check that. I am new to virtual box and everything. Any pointers will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TheHelpingMind I presume you're asking about detecting inputs over RDP? You can't prove that it's not possible. The sole fact that you or I didn't come up with a way to detect it doesn't mean anything. As I said, there may be some subtle patterns in the movement characteristics that are not detectable for a human, but could be recognized with an in-depth analysis or with an AI solution. Anyway, detecting that software is running in a VM definitely is possible and would already raise some suspicions - whether you're viewing/controlling it over RDP or not.

Comment: Thanks again. You cleared my doubts.